# How to put videos on a Sony Walkman NWZ-S545?

Tags: hardware, video, sony

So I have heard that it needs to be resized and be a different file type I think. How can I do this in Ubuntu?

Thanks!

Comment: To someone who remembers the [Sony Walkman cassette player](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/SONY_WM-D6C.jpg), this question sounds surreal.

Answer (score 2):

## [Avidemux](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/avidemux) [image: Install avidemux]

(You need to enable the multiverse repository for this to work):

- [How do I enable the "multiverse" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository)

Avidemux is a GTK application designed to allow you to easily resize, rescale and convert videos from one format to another. For your case it sounds perfect! According to the Sony website you just need to convert the videos to the MPEG-4 format however I can't seem to find the resizing information anywhere.

`sudo apt-get install avidemux`

Screenshot:

[image: Avidemux Screenshot]

Comment: I can't find it either.

Comment: Trial and error would be the best way to go then

Comment: I still can't find it. :(

Answer (score 1):

The best way to convert video, as always, is ffmpeg (`sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`).  This works for Sony NWZ-S545 (and E453, and probably S544, etc):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -b 567k -s 320x240 -vcodec mpeg4 -ab 220k -ar 44100 -ac 2 -acodec libfaac output.mp4
```

You'll need an faac encoder for this (libfaac on ubuntu); maybe it works without `-acodec libfaac` as well.

Comment: And if you do not have the libfaac encoder, just use this slightly modified command which uses the internal aac encoder: `ffmpeg -i inputfile -b 567k -s 320x240 -c:v mpeg4 -ab 220k -ar 44100 -ac 2 -c:a aac -strict experimental output.mp4`. You can find some more possibilities using mencoder and ffmpeg [here](http://fluxcoil.net/doku.php/hardwarerelated/sony_walkman_and_linux). Btw. I didn’t want to compile ffmpeg myself, I just downloaded the static build from [here](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/).

Answer (score 0):

## [WinFF](http://packages.ubuntu.com/winff) [image: Install WinFF]

WinFF is another nifty utility to convert video filetypes and sizes.

[image: WinFF Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the ones already posted, I'll recommend my personal favourite, [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/downloads.php) - but don't bother, it's pretty unintuitive to install and the others work great.

For your videos to play on this device, I think (I can't test it, obviously) you need to make sure to enter the following settings into whatever video conversion software you use:

Format: MPEG-4

Size: 320x240

Bit rate: 512 (fixed)

Frame rate: 30fps (also try 15)

I suggest you take a small video file and create a bunch with different settings, h265, h264, mpeg2 and so on and so forth. Then, put them all on the device and see if one works, use the same settings from then on. If the software you use comes with device presets, you can just *try out all of them*. (Pretty tedious I know, it should be your last resort)

These devices all require some relatively specific format of encoding, which is normally done by some * piece of software that is shipped with the device. Unfortunately, you will just have to somehow *find out* which settings are the right ones. A [google search](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=NWZ-S545+handbrake+profile&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=fb0beceb888e9115&cad=b) will often help, but it can also result in a lot of confusing and contradictory information.

Answer (score 0):

## [Arista Transcoder](http://www.transcoder.org/)[image: Install Arista]

As easy as it gets: just select the source (Font in the screenshot), and the target gadget and press the + button.

[image]