# How do I enable the "multiverse" repository?

Tags: package-management, software-center, software-sources

I keep seeing places refer to the "multiverse" repository as a place I can get software, how can I enable this repository? Please specify how to do this graphically and via command line.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The Multiverse repository contains packages (software) that is "not free" , referring to licensing restrictions.

> The Multiverse repository contains software which has been classified as non-free. This software may not be permitted in some jurisdictions. When installing each package from this repository, you should verify that the laws of your country permit you to use it. Also, this software may not include security updates.

For additional information on the philosophy of the ubuntu repositories, see [Overview of the default Ubuntu software repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/add-applications/C/default-repos.html)

You can enable the repository from the command line or graphically.

### Graphically

Open Software center, navigate to the "Ubuntu software" tab at the top, select (check off) multiverse.

[image: Software Center]

Use the "Reload" button to update your package list.

[image: Reload]

Note: This is called "Software and Updates" in recent versions (e.g. 20.10) of Ubuntu.

[image: new image]
([Image credits](https://askubuntu.com/a/1294941/124466))

#### Command line

Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` with any editor.

```
# command line editor (nano)
sudo -e /etc/apt/sources.list

# graphical editor
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Uncomment (remove the # from the front of) the `multiverse` lines or add them in if needed, so the lines look like this:

```
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric multiverse
#deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates multiverse
#deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates multiverse
```

Uncomment the `deb-src` lines if you need to download the source code (most users will not need the source code, so if in doubt, leave them disabled).

Save your edit (if you are using nano, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> , then type <kbd>Y</kbd> to save your changes) then, to update your package list, run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

- For additional information on managing your repositories, see [Ubuntu Wiki - Repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)

Comment: If the lines aren't present on that file, copy the existing ones from universe and replace the word 'universe' by 'multiverse'

Comment: Can someone update the screenshots, please? Thanks.

Comment: @minerz029 - there are already screenshots posted. See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - *update* <-. The screenshots are reflective of a outdated version of Ubuntu. I'm asking to have them updated with screenshots from a newer version.

Comment: You could use `sed`, to uncomment lines that end with `multiverse`: `sudo sed -i '/^#.*multiverse$/s/^# //g' /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Downvoted because the answer with `sudo apt-add-repository multiverse`  is so much nicer and more modern.

Comment: This was a rat-race, waste of time. See below answer "sudo apt-add-repository multiverse"

Answer (score 53):

Another option available for newer releases of Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-add-repository multiverse && sudo apt-get update
```

From the man page:

```
Examples:
  apt-add-repository 'deb http://myserver/path/to/repo stable myrepo'
  apt-add-repository 'http://myserver/path/to/repo myrepo'
  apt-add-repository 'https://packages.medibuntu.org free non-free'
  apt-add-repository http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
  apt-add-repository ppa:user/repository
  apt-add-repository multiverse
```

Comment: ... which requires some package that is not installed by default.

Answer (score 22):

From the command line without using a text editor or GUI:

```
sudo sed -i "/^# deb.*multiverse/ s/^# //" /etc/apt/sources.list
```

http://alestic.com/2012/05/aws-command-line-packages

Comment: Excellent. **And**, it's idempotent. Note, however, that it's aggressive -- all deb multiverse repos will be added, even those that are for building from src. To leave those out, add a space after "deb", so we have `sudo sed -i "/^# deb .* multiverse$/ s/^# //" /etc/apt/sources.list; sudo apt-get update`

Comment: At least in recent versions of Ubuntu, the multiverse source lines are not present in the sources.list file, only the multiverse security repo will be enabled by this command.