# Wireless network says no firmware and so I can't connect to the Internet

Tags: 12.04, wireless, dual-boot, firmware

I am running 12.04 LTS alongside Windows 7. When I boot into Ubuntu, it says that there is no firmware for a wireless network, and it shows "**no wireless network**" and I can't connect to the Internet. When I boot into Windows, it works fine.

How can I get it to work because I obviously need to be able to connect to the Internet for Ubuntu to be useful?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify what device it is for, but generally speaking, you should try these things first:

- Open *Additional Drivers* as described here: [How do I install additional drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-drivers)
- Make sure you've enabled `multiverse` repository (see [How do I enable the "multiverse" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository)) and install these two packages: [linux-firmware [image: Install linux-firmware]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/linux-firmware) and [linux-firmware-nonfree [image: Install linux-firmware-nonfree]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/linux-firmware-nonfree) with your favourite package manager.

  It should provide the firmware files you need.

The drivers and/or firmware aren't shipped with Ubuntu by default due to licensing issues.