# Ubuntu on Mac mini (late 2012)

Tags: drivers, mac-mini

I installed Ubuntu on my late 2012 Mac mini, but now I can't find/install the correct WiFi/Ethernet driver. Does anyone have a link to the correct driver and how to install it? Thanks!

The network devices on this machine are:

- Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:1686] (rev 01) with manually compiled kernel driver tg3
- Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 [14e4:4331] (rev 02) with kernel driver bcma-pci-bridge

Comment: Please edit your question including the output from the following commands: `lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A3` and `iwconfig`.

Comment: I have the same problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/290658/no-network-interfaces-detected-when-installing-ubuntu-server-on-mac-mini

Answer (score 0):

What more or less works is

`sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`

Alternatively, you can install the [tg3 drivers](http://www.broadcom.com/support/ethernet_nic/netxtreme_desktop.php) and [b43](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/all/linux-firmware-nonfree/download) drivers to get them working. I have attempted to document what I did [here](http://bharath.lohray.com/weblog/installing-mint-on-a-late-2012-macmini/).

Comment: @l0b0 - I think you have to enable a non-free repository. http://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository

Comment: Never mind, it's there now. Strange...