# How do I install playonlinux from the repository?

Tags: software-installation

I am getting following error while installing software from repository. Can anyone help me on this...

```
administrator@administrator-OptiPlex-380:~$ sudo apt-get install playonlinux
[sudo] password for administrator: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package playonlinux
```

Answer (score 2):

If you did not already do so, you will need to enable the **Multiverse** repository before trying to install `playonlinux`.  If you did not do that already, that is why you can't find the `playonlinux` package with `apt-get`.

[Please refer to this question and its answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository) which explains how to enable the multiverse repository.

Answer (score 2):

For `precise` run the below commands to install playonlinux:

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_precise.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Or

Download playonlinux.deb file from [`here`](http://www.playonlinux.com/script_files/PlayOnLinux/4.2.1/PlayOnLinux_4.2.1.deb)

**Note**: For precise and above you must install the package `wine:i386` to get `PlayOnLinux` working