# What program will change AVI Files into files I can burn on K3B to burn dvds?

Tags: files, dvd, burning, avi

I have AVI Files that are videos. Im am looking to burn these movies onto a DVD-R. It only burns as data to the disc if I burn it directly. So im wondering what program will convert these AVI Files to burnable files to watch on DVD player?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple program that do the trick is [DeVeDe](http://www.devede.org/).

To install it, you can use the version in [multiverse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository). Notice that I think that there is some strange interaction with the normal video packages (it will unisintall things like `libavutil51` to install `libavutil-extra-51`... it works for me, but can have collateral effects that I do not know).

It is straightforward to use.

[image: DeVeDe screenshot starting]

If it happens that you have to remove it, I post here the installation log, so that if needed you can re-install the other packages.

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  dvdauthor libavcodec-extra-53 libavformat-extra-53 libavutil-extra-51
  libpostproc-extra-52 libswscale-extra-2 mencoder
Suggested packages:
  mplayer-doc
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libavcodec53 libavformat53 libavutil51 libpostproc52 libswscale2
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  devede dvdauthor libavcodec-extra-53 libavformat-extra-53 libavutil-extra-51
  libpostproc-extra-52 libswscale-extra-2 mencoder
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 6,391 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7,455 kB of additional disk space will be used.
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the fast response Rmano! I actually installed and used DeVeDee when I was first searching the programs. I was having issues with the copies I was burning. Its real glitchy and the first thing that came to mind was that it was the program I chose to RE Create the avi file (DeVeDee) was the reason why. This assumption was after I slowed down the writing speen to X4 when noticing I still had this issue, even with other avi movie files I tried burning. Any other thoughts on this? Thank you all for your help