# Ubuntu 13.10 Wireless Issue

Tags: wireless, networking

I have recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my DELL laptop Inspiron E1505. It seems to work okay except I have yet to be able to connect to the wifi in my home. I have googled several answers on here but none have seem to work for me.

I cannot seem to find the `"System Settings -> Additional Drivers"`

I am a n00b but following all the advice from posts. I have gotten this from the terminal.

```
john@john-MM061:~$ iwconfig 
lo        no wireless extensions. 

john@john-MM061:~$ iwconfig 
lo        no wireless extensions. 

john@john-MM061:~$ sudo rfkill unblock all 
[sudo] password for john: 
john@john-MM061:~$ iwconfig 
lo        no wireless extensions. 

john@john-MM061:~$ sudo modprobe rtl8192cu 
john@john-MM061:~$ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan 
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning. 

john@john-MM061:~$ rfkill list all 
john@john-MM061:~$ dmseg | grep iwl 
No command 'dmseg' found, did you mean: 
 Command 'dmesg' from package 'util-linux' (main) 
 Command 'mmseg' from package 'sunpinyin-utils' (main) 
dmseg: command not found 
john@john-MM061:~$ dmesg | grep iwl 
john@john-MM061:~$ 
john@john-MM061:~$ 
john@john-MM061:~$ 
john@john-MM061:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2 
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX [14e4:170c] (rev 02) 
    Subsystem: Dell Inspiron 6400 [1028:01af] 
03:01.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller [1180:0832] 
-- 
0b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01) 
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1390 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:0007] 
    Kernel driver in use: wl 
john@john-MM061:~$ rfkill list all 
john@john-MM061:~$ rfkill unblock lan 
Bogus unblock argument 'lan'. 
john@john-MM061:~$ rfkill unblock wlan 
john@john-MM061:~$ sudo apt- get remove bcmwl-kernel-source 
sudo: apt-: command not found 
john@john-MM061:~$ sudo spt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source 
sudo: spt-get: command not found 
john@john-MM061:~$ lspci -k -vv | grep -A11-i wlan 
grep: 11-i: invalid context length argument 
john@john-MM061:~$ lspci -k -vv | grep -A11 -1 wlan 
john@john-MM061:~$ rfkill list all 
john@john-MM061:~$ rfkill list all 
john@john-MM061:~$
```

If I have to connect via ethernet cable, I know to plug it in but when I did that...still nada.

:) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try install the broadcom driver and wireless tools packages:

```
sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-common wireless-tools
```

Comment: It says E: Unable to locate package broadcom-sta-common

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository

Comment: Enable multiverse repository and it should find it

Comment: I followed the directions yet it shows up that it is disconnect but no option to log on to it...