# Can't find lubuntu restricted access extras

Tags: lubuntu, dvd, ubuntu-restricted-extras

Hi I am very very new to this.

Can't find the extras which will allow me to play DVD and music etc. Have found the code to manually input but have no idea how to do that. Help please and please keep it simple, everything else works fine so far

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Enable the `multiverse` repository and then update it.Finally install `lubuntu-restricted-extras` by running the below commands.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: Multi verse repository? VERY VERY NEW! How? Where?

Comment: see [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository) to enable multiverse repository.

Answer (score 0):

In the Lubuntu software center there aren't by default any restricted extras. But yesterday I installed the Ubuntu restricted extras and by far they run just fine.

Comment: enable the multiverse repository and then update it by running `sudo apt-get update`.After that run `apt-cache search lubuntu-restricted` command.