# youtube works with my xp but ubuntu

Tags: windows-xp

I have a self made computer amd pros gforce video card 6600gt running xp 
and my windows plays youtube fine but when I boot ubuntu it don't can anybody tell why

Comment: I have a questions about your question? First of all, what happens when you try to watch YouTube? Do you get an error? Second, when you say "amd pros", do you mean "AMD processor"? PS: I would always recommend using complete sentences when asking any website for help.

Answer (score 2):

You likely need flash player.

Open a terminal (control-alt-t), and type the following:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Once it's done installing, exit the terminal and then restart your browser.

You may possibly need to enable multiverse for this to work, see this link for how: [How do I enable the "multiverse" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository)

Comment: Assuming User258665 isn't using some outdated browser, shouldn't YouTube be able to fall back to HTML5 if FlashPlayer either fails or isn't even installed?