# Watching Netflix on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, software-installation, pipelight

When I attempt to install pipelight, an error message displays on the terminal:

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pipelight-multi : Depends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I follow these directions:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
```

When I attempt to enter the third command, it then displays that error above. I've been using Ubuntu for a few days now so, I'm still getting acclimated with everything. Any suggestions or tips would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have the multiverse repository enabled, which is where ttf-mscorefonts-installer lives.

Follow this question [How do I enable the "multiverse" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository) on how to enable it.

After that try again and proceed with enabling pipelight just to make sure

```
 sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight
```

Follow through with that and you should be good to watch Netflix in your desired browser.

Or you can install the Netflix app provided in the ppa

```
 sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop
```