# Adobe flash player installation on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, flash, adobe

Hiiii,

Please let me how to install adobe flash player plugin on Ubuntu 12.04 from command prompt.

Have already tried these below steps without any success.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extra
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Trying to make a image of Ubuntu using UCK with flash player plugin installed.

Comment: Could you please paste the output of the command line: "cat /proc/cpuinfo"? You might have one CPU which does not support SSE2, which is required for running the latest versions of Flash for Linux due to the compilation made by Adobe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Multiverse" option must be enabled in order to install the flashplayer plugin. Please, do enable it and then use the command: sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
More information in this answer: [How do I enable the "multiverse" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository).

Comment: Thanks this worked for me... Enabled multiverse, updated..Installed libnspr4-0d dependency and then installed flash by running #sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree.. Thank U Rishiag.