# How to install Broadcom wireless drivers offline?

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I have installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1. But the wifi is not working in Ubuntu (perhaps the drivers are not present), which worked fine in windows. Also I cant connect with Ethernet since my laptop does not have an Ethernet port. So is there any way for me to connect to the internet in ubuntu?
Edit: Output of the terminal command  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:

```
vikram@vikram-Inspiron-11-3148:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0018]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
vikram@vikram-Inspiron-11-3148:~$
```

I did what Pilot6 suggested. Here is the output:

```
vikram@vikram-Inspiron-11-3148:~$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
[sudo] password for vikram: 
Selecting previously unselected package bcmwl-kernel-source.
(Reading database ... 163804 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dkms.
Preparing to unpack dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04) ...
Setting up dkms (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.141+bdcom DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.16.0-30-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.16.0-30-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.16.0-30-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-30-generic
vikram@vikram-Inspiron-11-3148:~$
```

Comment: What about using a USB modem?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of "lspci -knn | grep Net -A2" terminal command.

Comment: @ln78 Please Edit Your title and add more info.

Comment: I updated the answer. They install new kernel, but old driver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing "fimware-b43-installer" offline](http://askubuntu.com/questions/730799/installing-fimware-b43-installer-offline)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to install wireless driver.

Insert your Ubuntu installation disk or a flash drive and copy these files from the installation disk to your Home directory:

```
pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_XXXXX.deb
pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_XXXXX.deb
```

Then run the following in terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

**If you have UEFI BIOS, you need to disable Secure Boot to load the driver.**

**18.04 update:**

The solution won't work on 18.04, because `build-essential` and its dependencies are not installed by default. The `dpkg` command will complain that dependencies are not installed.

You can manually find the required packages on the installation media ("pool" directory sorted by alphabet) and install them the same way as the `dkms` package. I hope nothing is missing there.

Comment: The second link is not working,can you please look into it and give an alternate place to download

Comment: I updated the link. But it will be changed from time to time.

Comment: I have just used this advice for Xubuntu 16.04 and installing the driver was no problem. I guess they have fixed the problem from 14.04.2.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン This problem is specific to 14.04.2 only. It has been fixed in 14.04.3, etc.

Comment: Worked on my MacBook pro 16.04 Broadcom BCM4360. You my good sir are a genius! Thanks for the help.

Comment: dkms & restricted folders missing in 18.04 lubuntu

Comment: @sureshvv They are  not missing, you can find them on the installation media. I see them there.

Comment: I have dowloaded both the Standard and Alternate installers. Don't see them. Only main and universe folders under pool. No restricted. No dkms in d folder. I see djvulibre and dmidecode.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/730799/installing-firmware-b43-installer-offline worked best

Answer (score 3):

I recently needed to install the Wifi firmware for an older repurposed iMac 9,1.  It had Broadcom 4322 Wifi, and Nvidia Ethernet, neither worked with 20.04.  It found the card and tried the correct module (b43) but complained via dmesg "firmware not found."

The following steps I found online worked:

- Find the broadcom firmware on another machine:

  - From: http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/
  - Download: `broadcom-wl-6.30.163.46.tar.bz2`  (or later)
  - Extract, then sneakernet back to the original box:
    `tar xjf broadcom-wl*`
- Install manually from Ubuntu Disc/Flash drive:

  `sudo dpkg -i ./pool/main/b43-fwcutter*.deb`
- Run the following:

  - `sudo b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware  broadcom-wl-*.o  # write to /lib`
  - `sync`
  - `sudo modprobe -r b43  # remove`
  - `sudo modprobe b43 # reload`

With that Network manager noticed and started up Wifi.  :-D

To automate the firmware update, this can be done now that the network is up:

- [Enable multiverse](https://askubuntu.com/q/89096/116108) in software-properties-gtk or apt/sources
- `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`

Comment: For beginners, to extract the file one must do: tar xjf broadcom-wl-6.30.163.46.tar.bz2