# Network & WiFi problem not working on lenovo G50-70

Tags: wireless, drivers, lenovo, ethernet

This is my first use of Ubuntu. I installed ubuntu 14.4  but the WiFi is not working. I don't understand how to activate them. What should I do?

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 && rfkill list`:

```
02:00.0 network controller [0280]: Broadcom corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4356](rev 01)
          subsystem: lenovo Device [17aa:0621]
          kernel driver in use:bcma-pci-bridge
```

`rfkill list`:

```
02:00.0 network controller [0280]: Broadcom corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4356](rev 01) subsystem: lenovo Device [17aa:0621] 
0:ideapad_wlan: wireless LAN 
soft blocked: no
hard Blocked: no
1: ideapad_blutooth: Bluetooth 
spft blocked:yes 
hard blocked:no
```

`iwconfig`:

```
eth0     no wireless extensions

lo       no wireless extensions
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add there output of "lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 && rfkill list" terminal command. Also specify your Ubuntu version.

Comment: And for Ethernet also "lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2"

Comment: You can try this solution for for wifi. http://askubuntu.com/a/626653/167850  After  that give "rfkill list"

Comment: Please give output of "lspci -knn | grep Net -A2" again. Does wifi work? If no, then add "iwconfig"

Comment: Add all information to your question. Give output of both commands. And full output, not partially. And your Ethernet should work BTW.

Comment: Please run again "lspci -knn | grep Net -A2" and what does "Kernel driver in use" show?

Comment: It looks like you did not install the driver. Did you do all what was suggested by the given solution. Did you download that driver from the net?

Comment: What do you mean? http://askubuntu.com/a/626653/167850  There is a link to a file. You need to copy it to your home folder and run that command again. It will install the correct driver, and wifi will work.

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to edit your question and remove Ethernet problem, and ask another question regarding wired network, if you like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Broadcom wireless drivers offline](http://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)