# Wi-Fi stops working frequently

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I recently keep having the problem that my internet stops working. On firefox, I get server not found. And the usual make sure that you didn't type ww instead of www.

Wi-Fi is still connected. A restart always fixes the problem. In Skype, I get multiple messages with people going offline at the exact same moment. Is there a way to fix this so I don't have to keep restarting it?

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4] (rev 10)
Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4]
Kernel driver in use: tg3
01:00.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Broadcom Corporation BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader [14e4:16bc] (rev 10)
--
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:00f5]
Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

### UPDATE:

It seems that Skype keeps fluctuating between everyone offline and some online. But it happens separately to when the browser stops working

---

I have a MacBook Pro with Ubuntu as a partition

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net  -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Done. I also recently donwloaded broadcom wl because 14e4:4331 was not supported

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Can you connect to internet by wire?

Comment: No I cannot. My ubuntu version is 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)

Comment: No. I am not asking how to download the wireless drivers. I already did so. But the internet fluctuates between working and not working. Wi-Fi still is connected when it stops working.

Comment: Your driver is not installed. That's why wireless works badly.

Comment: It isn't? I went through steps of installing the driver and after that, Wi-Fi started working. And then it started acting strange

Comment: Do it again. If there are errors, post them. It should show `Kernel driver in use: wl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wireless wl driver is not installed. You probably tried to install a wrong version that did not build for 14.04.

When wl driver is installed, `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` shows `Kernel driver in use: wl`

Install the driver [this way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline).

Comment: it turns out that installing the proper wl did work. It could've been a wrong version...