# Frequent timeouts on browser connection

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I asked [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/630940/wi-fi-stops-working-frequently) question before and now the problem came back. Every once in a while, I have to disable and re-enable Wi-Fi in order to make the browser work again. When the problem occurs, the page loads for a long time and then comes with a server not found or server timeout error. The output of `lspci -kknn | grep 0280 -A2` is:

```
$ lspci -kknn | grep 0280 -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:00f5]
Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Before the problem seemed to be installing the wrong driver. However, now I am using the wl kernel driver which is said to support my Broadcom Network Controller `[14e4:4331]`

---

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) as a partition on a MacBook Pro with Mavericks (10.9.5)

Comment: This suggests that the _wl_ driver is incorrect: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395

Comment: I tried that and I did `sudo modprbe -r wl` and `sudo modprobe b43` However `lspci` still shows Kernel Driver in use: wl I am still testing if the timeouts occur. As the answer said. You should test for 2-8 hours.

Comment: Is _wl_ still loaded? `lsmod`

Comment: `wl                   6367819  0 ` So wl seems loaded. I did `sudo modprobe -r wl` earlier though.

Comment: Another timeout happened. I will try reinstalling b43 and disabling wl.

Comment: I `rmmod` removed wl and activated b43. Now it said bcma-pci-bridge is in use. And when I tried `rmmod` on bcma, it said it was in use by b43

Comment: You need to install b43 first. Look at the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Please remove the incorrect driver:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

With a temporary working internet connection, install the required firmware:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot.