# Once Ubuntu 14.04LTS is installed, is it necessary to enable network devices or drivers? The eth0 and wlan0 are there, however they are unusable

Tags: drivers

XFX MG63Mi7109 LGA 775 NVIDIA GeForce 7100 / nForce 630i HDMI Micro ATX Intel Motherboard

TP-LINK TL-WDN4800 Dual Band Wireless N900 PCI Express Adapter,2.4GHz 450Mbps/5Ghz 450Mbps

Intel Core 2 Quad Q9300 2.50GHz Processor

Komputerbay 4GB 2X 2GB DDR2 800MHz PC2-6300 PC2-6400 DDR2 800 (240 PIN) DIMM Desktop Memory

```
# lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4321 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:01:05.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master
       configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=64
       resources: irq:19 memory:fe9fc000-fe9fffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 30:b5:c2:12:90:65
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.16.0-30-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:febe0000-febfffff memory:febd0000-febdffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: MCP73 Ethernet
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: f
       bus info: pci@0000:00:0f.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: a2
       serial: 00:1d:92:eb:5f:e9
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=forcedeth driverversion=0.64 duplex=full latency=0 link=yes maxlatency=20 mingnt=1 multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:45 memory:fe877000-fe877fff ioport:c880(size=8) memory:fe87e800-fe87e8ff memory:fe87e400-fe87e40f


# lspci | egrep -i --color 'network|ethernet'
00:0f.0 Ethernet controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP73 Ethernet (rev a2)
01:05.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1d:92:eb:5f:e9  
          inet6 addr: fe80::21d:92ff:feeb:5fe9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:296 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:325 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:325 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:24453 (24.4 KB)  TX bytes:24453 (24.4 KB)
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:b5:c2:12:90:65  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
# ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1d:92:eb:5f:e9  
          inet6 addr: fe80::21d:92ff:feeb:5fe9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:295 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:325 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:325 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:24453 (24.4 KB)  TX bytes:24453 (24.4 KB)
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:b5:c2:12:90:65  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Comment: Why there are two wireless adapters?

Comment: I installed a new one ( the one in the devices) recently because the older Broadcom card wasn't working with Ubuntu. I was working with Windows 7.

Comment: Does new one Atheros work?

Comment: Neither one does. No lights on, except on the new Atheros at boot. It then goes out and nothing,

Comment: Please add output of `rfkill list`.

Comment: And where do you connect the adapters? Your router? Can you see wireless networks in Network Manager?

Comment: $ rfkill list
0: phy1: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: You did not enable your wireless in Network Manager. Just click it. Or run in terminal `sudo rfkill unblock all`.

Comment: I double checked and the "wifi enabled" is checked. I also ran the command and nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your Broadcom wireless work this way. Tun in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo monprobe -r b43 bcma
sudo modprobe wl
```

And I suggest asking a separate question regarding your wired network adapter.

Comment: I have no internet on that machine. Is there a way to load those files on a another machine and use a usb to put them on?

Comment: @ClintJensen Yes, run `sudo apt-get source bcmwl-kernel-source` and that will download the source files that you can build on the other system.  You can also download directly from here:  http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/admin/bcmwl-kernel-source

Comment: Yes, there is a way. http://askubuntu.com/a/626653/167850 But I think the problem is somewhere else, since none of network adapters work. You may have some security restrictions or mac-filters in router, etc.

Comment: @Terrance That is wrong

Comment: @Pilot6 NO it is not!  I have done it here.

Comment: I tried to run the downloaded .deb and received a "Dependency is not satisfiable dkms"

Comment: Did you copy also "dkms_XXXXX.deb"? It is required.

Comment: You can find it on installation disk or [HERE](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04_all.deb)

Comment: Thanks, I got the dkms and the kernel to install then I rena the modprobe -r b43 bcma. It seemed to like that, meaning that it gave no errors. Then I ran the modprobe wl and got a modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found.

Comment: Did bcmwl-kernel-source install without errors?

Comment: Yes. No errors. only when I tried to run the sudo modprobe wl.

Comment: That is weird. And also that all other devices do not work. What is your kernel version. `uname -r`?

Comment: 3.16.0-30 generic.

Comment: Looks OK. All is strange. I have no ideas for this format. You can try ubuntuforums.org in "Network and wireless". You can find people there who can debug it.