# I can't connect to wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu, network-manager

I was trying to connect to wi-fi with lubuntu but I could not,
I don't know exactly what is the problem, I used nm-applet and that was the result:

```
    nm-applet

** (nm-applet:13926): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files

(nm-applet:13926): nm-applet-WARNING **: Failed to register as an agent: (32) An agent with this ID is already registered for this user.
nm-applet-Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon
```

---

UPDATE:

So I re-install it and tried again, the result as following:

```
family@family-HP-Compaq-6735s:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM4312 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller [103c:137d]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
family@family-HP-Compaq-6735s:~$  nm-applet

** (nm-applet:2333): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
nm-applet-Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon

(nm-applet:2333): nm-applet-WARNING **: Failed to register as an agent: (32) An agent with this ID is already registered for this user.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 1):

If you can connect to internet by wire, then just run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -r b43 bcma
```

If you can't connect another way, then use [THIS METHOD](https://askubuntu.com/a/626653/167850)

Answer (score 0):

For me, installing 'at-spi2-core' allowed me to run nm-applet successfully, and connect to a wifi network.

```
sudo apt install at-spi2-core
```