# I just installed Ubuntu 14 for the first time and cannot get the wireless to work

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

I just installed Ubuntu 14 on my laptop for the first time. After the installation I had no Wi-Fi connection. I went to "Edit Connections" and created a "Wi-Fi Connection", but don't know how to answer the questions such as SSID, Mode, BSSID, Device MAC address, Cloned MAC address, and MTU.

Can one of you gurus please help me?

Many thanks in advance and have a nice day.

Regards,
Majid Chavoshi

Thanks for your assistance, below please find the output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82567LM Gigabit Network         Connection [8086:10fs] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:024f]
Kernel driver in use: e1000e

oc:oo.o Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]
Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: An please don't create new connections. It is for another purpose. You just need to install a proper driver.

Comment: @mikewhatever This is not a duplicate of the question that provides guidance on how to ask this sort of question. It is most definitely related.

Comment: Also I did a #cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i wireless

Comment: Also. I did a #cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i wireless

Comment: See the Broadcom help at  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx    The b43 driver works fine, you just need to add the required firmware, which used to be in linux-firmware-nonfree or you might have to install the b43-fwcutter package.  Definitely many other question relate to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a wired connection, run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and Wi-Fi will work.

If you do not have a wired connection use [THIS GUIDE](https://askubuntu.com/a/626653/167850).

Comment: Hi There, thanks for your assistance. Below please find the output of the command:root@Eclectic-Consulting:~# apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package bcmwl-kernel-source
root@Eclectic-Consulting:~#

Comment: @MajidChavoshi If you do not have connection to internet, then it is normal output. Use offline guide.

Comment: I setup a static IP, I do have connection to the Internet.     root@Eclectic-Consulting:~# ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:70:e5:b4:d4  
          inet addr:172.21.52.83  Bcast:172.21.53.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::221:70ff:fee5:b4d4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:51059 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15791 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:29893755 (29.8 MB)  TX bytes:2077324 (2.0 MB)

Comment: @MajidChavoshi Then run `sudo apt-get update` and try again.

Comment: You are a genius dude, kudos to you! I don't have access to any wireless network now to test it, but I'm pretty sure it'll work.

Comment: @MajidChavoshi So you can accept the answer by clicking "bird" at the left.