# Wifi Problem with dual booting Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1

Tags: 14.04, wireless, dual-boot

So I've installed both Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu (dual-booting), and the for the most part, I have followed instructions. However, right now I can't figure out why my wifi on my Ubuntu does not work. When I click on the Network icon, the "Enable Wifi" does not even appear.

My machine is the Lenovo Flex 2, 15 inch.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 && rfkill list

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n[14e4:4365] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0621]
        Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 && rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But I've added that information!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

will fix it.

[Offline Guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/626653/167850).

Comment: I tried that, but then it asks me to insert the disc labeled

'Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20150218.1)'

Comment: As soon as I mount the iso file, the file unmounts and it prompts me again for the iso file....

Comment: @Pilot6: look at duplicate...  **;-)**

Comment: @Edasaur Do you have a wired internet connection? If not use offline guide.

Comment: @Fabby Duplicate is very good but too complex.

Comment: Duplicate is very good *and thorough* thus not very easy...   **;-)**

Comment: @Pilot6, it worked! Thank you so much!

Out of curiosity, how do you guys know so much about debugging ubuntu problems?

Comment: @Edasaur Just read http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers, and you will know as much as we do ))