# detects all wifi except my own

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, broadcom

i have a lenovo ideapad G480 and ubuntu 14.04.02. my laptop detects every other wifi but not my own. i have also checked the connection and it is working on every other device. could anyone help me solve this. Thanks

heres some info that may help.

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"
Linux umar-Lenovo-G480 3.16.0-41-generic #55~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sun Jun 14 18:43:36 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
umar@umar-Lenovo-G480:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet [1969:1090] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3979]
    Kernel driver in use: alx
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:0587]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
umar@umar-Lenovo-G480:~$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=27 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

umar@umar-Lenovo-G480:~$ rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

*-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8162 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 08
       serial: b8:88:e3:76:bd:2d
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=192.168.0.102 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:46 memory:db500000-db53ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:db400000-db403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 08:ed:b9:a4:43:97
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=3.16.0-41-generic firmware=610.812 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:0587]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Comment: Provide information about the access point ("your wifi" - I assume) which isn't recognized.

Comment: im sorry but i dont get it. what information do u mean. the router is dlink. the connection used to connect to this laptop but then suddenly dissappeared yesterday. and i have tried almost everything that i could find as a solution to similar problems but it didnt work. finally i re-installed ubuntu. that didnt work either. if theres a specific command you would like me to to run and show the reslult to that here i can do that. ive aded some more result info on top if that helps. Thanks

Comment: What channel is the router on?

Comment: You may want to format a little... The issue is likely to be located on your access point device and you're not providing any information about it - except that it's a dlink device.

Comment: how do i check what channel the router is on? and what else information do you want to know about the device?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: You can check channel in your router admin web page.

Comment: @Pilot6 
 
output added... and the bandwidth is 20/40Mhz (auto) -channel 13

Comment: Change channel to something in 1-11. 12 and 13 are not allowed in US. Firmware of wireless card may be set to US.

Comment: @Pilot6   ive got only two options there. which are 20 Mhz and 20.40Mhz (auto). at 20 Mhz the channel comes as N/A and on the auto it comes as 13.  and if its the case that you said it still doesnt explain how my wifi was detectable and working before and now it isnt. what do i do?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy. Connect to internet by wire and run

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If you can't connect by wire use [THIS GUIDE](https://askubuntu.com/a/626653/167850).

Comment: tried this... didnt solve the problem. my wifi still isnt listed in the detected wifi list.