# Broadcom wireless network driver won't install offline

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom

My Ubuntu 14.04 does not have network access. I tried installing the driver as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626642) but it doesn't work. I get the exact same error message as ln78 complains about.

Pilot6 responded to this question by saying that he now adapted the answer so it should work now and it apparently worked for ln78 but it doesn't work for me.

### In fact, it works now. For some reason, I though I was working with Ubuntu 14.2 but it actually is Ubuntu 14.04. So the adaptation of the answer by Pilot6 does apply to me. I tried it and it now works! (Sincere apologies for not knowing my Ubuntu version and thanks for the attempt to help out)

On request by @Pilot6, I now add the output of the `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac  Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0019]
```

---

On the suggestion by @Pilot6 to write down everything I did before (which I had no idea about; I tried so many things) I managed to reinstall my ubuntu installation (still alongside with Windows 8) on my Dell XPS 13. It fails in the exact same way. Here is the terminal output:

```
oem@Alex-laptop:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0    40M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0   128M  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0     2G  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  97,7G  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0 351,6G  0 part 
├─sda7   8:7    0     8G  0 part 
├─sda8   8:8    0   9,2G  0 part /
└─sda9   8:9    0   7,9G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1   7,5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1   7,5G  0 part /media/oem/17B0-C420
oem@Alex-laptop:~$ cp /media/oem/17B0-C420/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04_all.deb .
oem@Alex-laptop:~$ cp /media/oem/17B0-C420/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb .
oem@Alex-laptop:~$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
[sudo] password for oem: 
Selecting previously unselected package bcmwl-kernel-source.
(Reading database ... 165879 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dkms.
Preparing to unpack dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04) ...
Setting up dkms (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.141+bdcom DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.16.0-30-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.16.0-30-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.16.0-30-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-30-generic
oem@Alex-laptop:~$
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe step-by-step what you did. Did you install dkms deb file? Did you download driver from the link I gave?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really don't know all the things I tried. Some of them were many weeks ago. Each time I found a new suggestion on the internet, I tried it without success. So I cannot really tell you in a detailed way all the things a tried. What I tried last weekend is exactly what you recommend. Probably, I should reinstall my Ubuntu installation but this, for me, is a challenge in itself. I will try it this weekend. Thanks again and apologies for not being able to provide the required information.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Broadcom wireless drivers offline](http://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline)

Answer (score 0):

OP's answer.

In fact, it works now. For some reason, I though I was working with Ubuntu 14.04.2 but it actually is Ubuntu 14.04. So the adaptation of the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/626653/167850) by Pilot6 does apply to me. I tried it and it now works! (Sincere apologies for not knowing my Ubuntu version and thanks for the attempt to help out)