# For a 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04 install, How to install Broadcom wireless 32 bit drivers offline

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom, 32-bit

I have found the steps for doing this with the 64 bit installation of Ubuntu, and I assume that the steps are the same for the most part with the exception of the actual files used. I need some direction on where to find the 32 bit drivers. The post that I have found that covers the 64 bit install can be found [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline)

Thank you so much for any help. This is my first install and so far I am loving it.

Comment: I will update for 32-bit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Broadcom wireless drivers offline](http://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline)

Comment: Ok I see that Pilot6, that you so much.

Comment: @RogerLoper, for general case, you can always search for packages or their contents using http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Thank you Sneetsher, still learning as this is my first linux install, so I have alot to learn.