# How do I get my wireless card working

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom

Hello guys I have problem with changing wifi channel on my wireless card. I am in Norway at the moment and I live in Bosnia, when I came here I can't find home network. My theory is that I have problem with wireless card channel (I see many wireless networks but not one I want to connect to) so I am trying to change it but when I use command:

`sudo iwconfig wlan0 channel 1`

I get this error:

```
Error for wireless request "Set Frequency" (8B04) :
SET failed on device wlan0 ; Device or resource busy.
```

I tried using command: `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down`

and then change channel but I got same results.

This is info about my wifi card:

```
 wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"dlink"  
           Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 1C:BD:B9:B9:F7:44   
           Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=27 dBm   
           Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
           Encryption key:off
           Power Management:off
           Link Quality=62/70  Signal level=-48 dBm  
           Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
           Tx excessive retries:55  Invalid misc:126   Missed beacon:0
```

I use toshiba satelite c660 laptop.
After: `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`
I got:

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313
802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)     Subsystem: Askey Computer Corp. Device [144f:7175]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

Comment: You can't change channel this way. The channel can be changed only at Access Point, not at the client side.

Comment: How can I change frequency at which my wifi card works?

Comment: Your wifi card works at frequency that is set up in the router it is connected to. You can't change it. But you can change frequency in router settings.

Comment: I have no that option my internet provider doesn't give access to modem. I have no idea why I can't see my internet connection.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command. If it as a built in wireless card.

Comment: I did as instructed, thx for all help till now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to internet by wire and run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

This will install the proper driver.

If you can't connect with cable, you can use an [offline guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/626653/167850)

Comment: I know it is noobish question but what are proper drivers for my laptop.

Comment: Just run that command and that will download and install wireless driver.

Comment: Okey thanks for help I will do it now and will be back with answer soon.

Comment: I can't connect with cable I guess I have problem with those drivers too so I will try to fix it later, now I have to make lunch. Tahnk you for all help u provided, wish u best.

Comment: @guber90 I gave a link to offline guide.