# Can't connect to Wifi in Ubuntu Gnome 14.04

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, gnome, broadcom

I just switched from windows to linux today so I'm a noob at this. Now, I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 14.04. I can't find any network icon on the top bar which is mentioned in the GNOME Help manual. I looked up a few tutorials and they keep mentioning that I need to install some extra driver or something like that. Any help?

I typed the command
 lspci -knn | grep Net -A2terminal

In the terminal and this is the output:

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e071]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: Press simultaneously Ctrl+Alt+T. Terminal window will open. Enter there the command and post output to your question. It will show what wireless adapter you have. And we will advise how to install a driver for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect to internet by wire and run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If you can't connect by wire, use [OFFLINE GUIDE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline/626653#626653)