# HP Pavilion dm1 - wifi does not work with ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom, hp-pavilion

before anything else, please note that I am a complete newbie with Ubuntu. I can open a terminal and thats pretty much it.

After updating kubuntu version, my notebook crashed. I am at a health resort and will not return home for next three weeks. The wifi here is without password, after connecting you use a voucher code to unlock browsing.

Using a bootable flash drive (my friend sent it to me in mail) I installed a fresh ubuntu 14.04 lts. The thing is, the internet is deadly slow or does not work at all. I can access internet from my phone.

I have hp pavilion dm1. How can I run something to give you details about my hw?

I have been searching internet and trying everything for the past theee days. Nothing worked. I'm desperate. Please help.

lspci command output

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01) 
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1795] 
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Working on it, just a second. I need to find out how to create a text document that my phone can open.

Comment: You can try [this solution](http://askubuntu.com/a/626653/167850)  but there is no guarantee with this chip. Broadcom claims that this driver should work.

Comment: I just logged in from my computer. It worked. **THANK YOU!** Is there anything I can do to repay you? Send you a postcard? :)