# can't update drivers through software & updates

Tags: drivers, updates

so I decided to install Ubuntu desktop 14.04 on my windows pc 
(dual boot) and I installed it from usb.
once I open the software & updates app and select additional drivers tab, I select the WiFi driver (broadcom 802.11)
and nVidia binary driver for my graphics card than I click "apply changes" and it starts loading and than stops and doesnt change anything...
I don't have access to internet because of it... help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What kind of computer do you have? If its a dell you either have to search up Network connections on your computer and get the wi-fi through that way. If it doesn't work try hooking up your computer to your motum and the typing the password to your wi-fi when your hooked up to it. I have had to do this with dell computers. Hope this helps.

Comment: well my PC is a Lenovo brand, when i was booting ubuntu from USB it was fine I could update my WiFi driver no problems than i decided to install to hard drive and after that it just cant update... nothing happens really... im really confused because i dont know much about ubuntu..

Comment: Did you go to Search your computer and online sources in the left corner of Ubuntu, and search Network connections?

Answer (score 0):

Install the proprietary Broadcom Linux STA Wireless drivers in an alternative way.

Connect the ethernet adapter of your computer with a LAN cable to your router.

Open a **terminal** by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and execute these commands :

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install dkms  
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Now you should be able to connect to your wireless network.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have no internet connection.

The "Additional Drivers" are downloaded from internet.
You need to connect by wire, then you will be able to install them.

If there is no easy way to connect to internet without the wireless driver, then you will need to install the Broadcom driver offline. After that you will be able to install the Nvidia drivers.

[Here is a guide to install Broadcom drivers](https://askubuntu.com/a/626653/167850).