# BCM4360 wifi driver offline download available?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers

I'm trying to find the wifi driver for Broadcom BCM4360 rev 3 for my Ubuntu computer but I don't have wifi or Ethernet available for the pc. is there a driver that supports bcm4360 that can be downloaded onto a flash drive and installed that way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Broadcom wireless drivers offline](http://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline)