# Ubuntu 14.4.3 how to fix wifi on lenovo yoga 2 11

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I reinstallled my Ubuntu just now and i typed to CMD rfkill list but it showed this:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

And after lspci-knn | grep Net -A2 it showed this:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0611]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

So what i am supposed to do if my wifi doesnt work (my pc cant find any) and i dont have connection to internet only on my mobil phone.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: If you can't connect to internet, then refer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline

Comment: IDK what to do with this: sudo dpkg -i *.deb ... this sign * means that there i must type full name of that file what i want to install? Becouse i did it and i got error

Comment: Just run this command as it is. it will be substituted itself. Or type in the file name, if you have other deb files there.

Comment: Thank you very much :) how can i give you some reward? :)

Comment: You are welcome! As soon as you get some rep, you will be able to upvote that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the proprietary BROADCOM Linux drivers.

Open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source  
sudo reboot
```

When you don't have Internet access or cannot connect to a router via Ethernet adapter - install BROADCOM Wireless Linux STA drivers offline, following this guide from @Pilot6: [offline install](https://askubuntu.com/a/626653/260935)

Comment: I cant do that becouse I dont have imternet connection :/

Comment: @user3396072 I gave you a link to my answer with directions how to install this driver offline.

Comment: @user3396072: for clarity: Pilot6 is referring to [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline)

Comment: You may mention disabling secure boot in case of troubleshooting.