# Checking for WIFI Drivers before installing

Tags: wireless, system-installation

How do I know if the ubuntu install will have my network drivers? I have a laptop with no ethernet connector, only wifi.

How can I make sure that the installation will have the wifi drivers before I try to install? Looking to install 14.04 on my Dell XPS 13 laptop.

--

```
lspci -knn | greg Net -A2

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:019]
```

Comment: Boot from Live USB and check the adapter. It should work.

Comment: Booted to live Kubuntu 14.04 CD. No wi-fi drivers seem to be loaded. I looked at Network Settings and there is no option to configure wifi. I guess that means no support for my hardware? Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command. You probably need to install drivers.

Comment: Sure, the output is as above. I would think that's a fairly common driver as broadcom is a popular wi-fi adapter.

Comment: So it is supported.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Broadcom wireless drivers offline](http://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline)

Comment: Broadcom is indeed popular BUT broadcom has no love for Ubuntu ;)

Comment: But there are still drivers. Installing offline is not quite easy. I really have no clue why the installer can't do it easier, since the driver is on the installation media.

Comment: I believe the earlier version of `bcmwl-kernel-source` included in 14.04 doesn't yet support the newer 14e4:43b1. I suggest you try the live USB for Ubuntu 15.10 instead.