# Ubuntu 15.10 Suspend / Resume blackscreen caused by Broadcom driver after no-internet install

Tags: networking, drivers, 15.10, suspend, broadcom

Ubuntu 15.10 Suspend / Resume blackscreen caused by Broadcom driver after no-internet install of drivers.

On a Dell XPS 15 with a Broadcom BCM4352 [14e4:43b1]

On a clean install of Ubuntu 15.10 the network card is not recognized. I can suspend the machine and it wakes up fine. After looking around a lot

After looking at this: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) 
and this:[How to install Broadcom wireless drivers offline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline)

I pick these from the install USB: 
pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_XXXXX.deb
pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_XXXXX.deb
and run this command: 
sudo dpkg -i *.deb

After this the card works (if I reboot it will ask me for the wireless password before logging in, even  if I have clicked let all users use the card).

The big problem is I cannot suspend resume. On suspend, it will suspend, on resume, it looks like it starts up, but then nothing happen and I get the infamous blackscreen.

I have tried to update the machine after, I have tried just about any graphics driver, and nothing changes.Its on the broadcom driver install this happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a bug of Broadcom drivers. Report it to launchpad.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the Broadcom wireless card that came with my XPS 15 with an Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260 worked for me - I can finally resume my system after being suspended.

Notes:

- The Broadcom card is 3x3 and the Intel is 2x2, so replacing the Broadcom with the Intel would leave 1 antenna disconnected
- I used [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDV_7XGkexU) as reference when switching the wireless cards