# Right WiFi modul loaded only in Live USB mode, not when OS installed on hard drive

Tags: wireless, broadcom

My laptop has Broadcom BCM 43228 wifi chip. I know that a right module for this chip is *wl*. In live mode when I do:

```
lsmod | grep b43
```

I get nothing which is good, b43 is not the driver I need for this chip. Then I add *wl* module like this. Because I'm not connected to the internet, I guess apt-get installs it from the USB.

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

After that I can see my wifi SSID and internet connection works. When I do:

```
lsmod | grep wl
```

I get:

```
wl                   6365184  0
cfg80211              548864  2 wl,mac80211
```

which means wl is loaded and everything is fine. However when I install Ubuntu, b43 is loaded, wifi isn't working and I can't install wl module. It says that I don't have internet connection. Ethernet is not an option, I don't have a wire close. Bluetooth and mobile tethering is also not an option right now.

Is there an easy solution? Blacklist b43, install wl from USB? I see that bcmwl on the USB drive but when I try dpkg -i bcmwl-... it throws me dependencies errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Broadcom wireless drivers offline](http://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline)

Comment: I tried that, but it says gcc is not installed http://imgur.com/mZ5LClh
Could the solution be not to install updated kernel when installing on hard disk?

Comment: That is weird, because these packages should be installed by default. So this is probably not Ubuntu.

Comment: @Pilot6 `gcc` and compilers aren't auto loaded.  `build-essential` getting installed includes the compilers - default systems don't get it if I remember the layout of the ISOs and meta packages.

Comment: It is Ubuntu with KDE, Kubuntu. So I don't need to ne helped if it's not Unity?

Comment: The easiest way is to connect to internet by wire and install the driver.

Comment: Yes I know, but right now I don't have access to wire and this is not a solution because in live mode everything works, so all files are here.