# Can't log onto internet

Tags: 14.04, wireless, internet

I have just downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 but I'm unable to connect to the internet. I travel a lot and connect to WiFi hotspots at various bars and restaurants. No home service.

In Windows 7, I just ask the bartender or waitress the password, type it in, and I'm connected. Not so in Ubuntu.

Computer is brand new, Lenovo 11e. AMD A4-6210 APU with AMD Radeon R3 Graphics.
Four gigs of RAM. 64-bit operating system. Windows 7 installed.

There is a “windshield wiper” type icon in the upper right hand corner of my desktop that seems to refer to connecting to the internet:

I click the windshield icon and I get three choices: Option # 1: VPN Connections and an option to configure VPN- click on that and I get a window that says Ethernet and an “ADD” button.

Option #2: Enable Networking. Click on that and I get “Disconnected.”

Option #3: Edit Connections – click on that and get I get Ethernet, Wired connection 1. And the “ADD” button.

Can someone walk me through this maze? Please realize I am in a foreign country and can't speak the language. The guy behind the counter doesn't know what a router is.  He does not know what a Connection Name is. Nor a SSID, a BSIDD or a MAC Address is. And frankly, neither do I. Just tell me, in plain English, where to type in the bar's password so I can get connected.

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-connect.html

Comment: It sounds like your wifi is not being seen. Make sure that if there is a hardware radio disable switch, it has not been switched to disable, but is set to the enabled position. If it is enabled and no access points are listed in that network menu, then it is possible you are using a computer with a wireless card which does not have open drivers in the Linux kernel. Please update your question to include the output of `sudo lshw -c network`

Comment: Wow! This is getting way too complicated! Let me look.

Comment: I have looked at this and, frankly, I have no idea what either or you are talking about. I appreciate your help but PLEASE tell me what you want me to do in plain English.

Comment: The easiest way to confirm @ngng's suspicion is to [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: Thank you David, but I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that your Lenovo 11e uses the same WIFI adapter as [this Lenovo 11e](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Thinkpad/11e/jessie):

> Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
>   [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)

- Download the necessary packages [dkms](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.5_all.deb) and [bcmwl-kernel-source](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb) on Windows. see [answer of Pilot6](https://askubuntu.com/a/626653/386067).
- Reboot into Ubuntu.
- Open necessary Windows partitions (drives) with a [file manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/files.html). If you use Wubi, one partition is already open in the folder `host` in [root directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory).
- open a [Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal).
- Navigate to Windows download folder with terminal command `cd`. e.g. :

  `cd /host/Users/bcripps/Downloads`
- List available files with

  `ls`
- Install the downloaded packages with

  `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

Comment: Thanks ngng, but it does not sound like plain English to me, but I will see how far I get... Bry

Comment: Downloaded dkms and bcmwl-kernel-source. Now where is this File Manager located in Ubuntu? And I don't know what a Partition is...

Comment: @bcripps: [Here](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2014/04/ubuntu-14-04-review-stable-responsive-polished) are some pictures of the File Manager. It has a drawer icon with file cards on the left sidebar. Partition is a part of a hard disk. On Windows it has a drive letter. e.g. C:  If you open a partition on Ubuntu it is "mounted" in a file path. /host for your Windows drive with Wubi Ubuntu, /media/yourname/id for other Windows drives. e.g. **C:\Users\yourname\Downloads** on Windows could be **/host/Users/yourname/Downloads** or  **/media/yourname/id/Users/yourname/Downloads** on Ubuntu

Comment: @bcripps: If you open the File Manager `CTRL` and `L` shows you the file path or in the menu of the File Manager `Go` -> `Enter location...`. In the left sidebar of the File Manager "Volume" is a drive on Windows. "Computer" shows you the root directory (=folder which includes all other folders and files)

Comment: Ok. I clicked on the Drawer Icon and when it opened up, I hit CTRL and L and I got /home/bc in the bar across the top of the screen. Is this right? Thank you....Bry

Comment: @bcripps: This is right. If you change `/home/bc` to `/host`, is it possible to find your Windows folder with your downloaded files ? I assume the path is `/host/Users/bc/Downloads`. If you found the downloaded files, press CTRL and L again and use the shown path for cd command in the terminal: e.g. `cd /host/Users/bc/Downloads` and then type `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` to install them.

Comment: Sorry for delay. Wendy's has been closed. Typed in /host. Nothing happened until I hit “enter” (Please don't leave out details.) Got 13 folders: Boot; mfg; PerfLogs; ProgramData; ProgramFiles; ProgramFiles (x86); $RecycleBin; support; SW Tools; System Volume Infromation; ubuntu; Users; Windows...

and then some other documents: bootmgr; BOOTSECK.BAK; Documents and Settings; hiberfil.sys; pagefile.sys; wubildr; Wubildr.mbr... This make any sense to you?

Comment: It makes sense. After hitting "enter", you saw your Windows files. If you open "Users", then "bc" (I assume that this is your name on Windows) and "Downloads", you should find your downloaded driver files for Ubuntu.

Comment: Ok ngng... Thanks for hanging in with me. Not sure what I did, but I downloaded the two files and I see them listed under the first icon on the desktop: Search Your Computer. They are listed under: Files and Folders. Now how do I install them?

Comment: @bcripps It seems that you don't want the [Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal). OK. The alternate method is: double click on the found package file dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.5_all.deb . It should open Software Center. Click on Install.  It should install this package. Repeat the procedure with the second package (bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb). Done.

Comment: Under Files & Folders, I have 2 files: bcmwl-kernal...Oubuntu0.2_amd64 and bcmwl-kernel...untu0.2_amd64.deb I double click onl the first and get 2 files: DEBIAN and usr. I double click on the second and the Ubuntu Software Center opens and says: "Dependensy is not satisfable: dkms. Error this package contains Broadcom 802.11 Oinus STA and then a bunch of other stuff.... Help!!!!

Comment: @bcripps "Dependency is not satisfiable: dkms" means that you have to install the dkms package [dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.5_all.deb](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.5_all.deb) first.

Comment: Once again, sorry for the delay but I'm losing my enthusiasm for this nonsense. Ubuntu says the program is installed. What's next?

Comment: If both packages are installed (Software Center needs sometimes a double-click to install it),  Wifi should work after next reboot. If it still doesn't work, I can't help you. I can ask some experts around me but without  some information from [Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal), I get also no help from the experts.

Comment: Thanks ngng... is there a way I can be certain that both packages are installed? David, above, mentions network diagnostics...

Comment: If you use a [Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal): `dpkg -l` shows all packages. The packages with ' ii` are installed. Add "| grep" to filter packages:  `dpkg -l | grep dkms` and  `dpkg -l | grep bcmwl`

Comment: Do you want me to type dpkg -1 someplace? Or is there someplace that I'm supposed to click on it? Thanks, Bry

Comment: `dkpg -1` is wrong because 1 (one) and l (L in lower case) are different. You should run the [Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal)<- Click on it for further information. A possible way to run the Terminal is to use the search icon. The search icon is the first icon on the top of the left side (white spiral with Ubuntu logo). Click on it. A line opens where you can type `terminal` Now you should see an icon below with `>_`. Click on it. It opens a window where you can type all commands I wrote in my previous posts.

Comment: I want to thank you, ngng, for all the effort you put into this. You deserve an award for patience. But I'm afraid I'm done with it. I uninstalled Ubuntu this morning and don't care if I ever hear the name again. I understand now, why Bill Gates made all that money. He made it easy.

Anyway, good luck to you. 
Bry