# MacBookPro11,3 wifi issue with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless, mac, macbook-pro

Good Day All,

I have been having issues getting wifi to work in Ubuntu 16.04 on my MacBookPro11,3. Installation of the Broadcom drivers found [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8) leads to dependency issues. If anyone has any experience with this issue, help would be greatly appreciated.

[When I try to install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mQfj.png)

From OS X System Report:

> en0: Card Type: AirPort Extreme (0x14E4, 0x134) Firmware Version:
>   Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.95.175.1a6)

Regards,

AnimalStyle

*Saint Christopher & Nevis, West Indies*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Broadcom wireless drivers offline](http://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with 12.10 on my macbook pro 11.3 I found the correct driver package off ubuntu website, while in OSX, and put it on a usb, then rebooted in ubuntu with rEFInd,  put it on my desk top, purged the old with:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

//then:

```
cd ~/Desktop

sudo dpkg -i *.deb

sudo modprobe wl

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

sudo apt-get update
```

Then went into update manager it ran through some changes then into setting to see the driver then correctly displayed clicked on it hit apply, restarted and it worked like a dream. Here I'll upgrade myself real quick and see if I can get it working in 16.04 as-well I love fixing broke things.

/*And yes I know I went into overkill with update, but once more wifi from 
phone, kept loosing signal and didn't want to miss anything.*/

---

Yes, just updated myself, same process, you can find the correct packages in your install disk by mounting it from any other os you downloaded it on, or usb you hooked up to load it, and search for the bcmwl package grab the box and drag it onto your desktop then do the commands above, you will also need dkms, you can find either when the disk is mounted and your are viewing the files in the seach bar, then

```
cd ~/Desktop

sudo dpkg -i *.deb

sudo modprobe wl

sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I did this and it throws me a bunch of errors on dpkg command and then `modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.13.0-32-generic`