# How to enable Broadcom Wireless Driver by Terminal on 16.04 LTS?

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, broadcom

I have just installed **`ubuntu 16.04 LTS`**. When I choose try before installing, wifi was not working. So I activated wifi driver by **`Software & Updates >> Additional Drivers`** and It was working while installing (and try before installing).

But after installing, I am not able to activate by same procedure. When I enable and input my password, it does nothing.

Output of `lspci --vvnn | grep -A 9 Network`

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 19
    Region 0: Memory at f7c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

output of `iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
enp9s0    no wireless extensions.
```

My problem is I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 and not able to enable wireless driver.

-- Software & Updates >> Additional Drivers

-- Select Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA Wireless driver source from ....

-- When I insert password, nothing happen, It still selected *Do not use this device*

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.

Comment: @Pilot6 it's already disabled and I already checked http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers (but it did not solve my problem)

Comment: What you did and what was the problem?

Comment: @Pilot6 I just installed and not able to enable wireless driver by GUI.

Comment: What did you install? Your output shows that you did not. You need to install `bcmwl-kernel-source`. And there is no need to activate anything in GUI.

Comment: I just fresh installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS (OS not driver)

Comment: Run `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source`. Nothing else is needed.

Comment: @Pilot6 how can I install this without internet ? It was working fine while using before installing (try mode)\

Comment: There is a link to this question in the manual I linked before. It seems you did not bother to read it carefully. http://askubuntu.com/a/626653/167850

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks buddy :) It's solved now :) I am new to Linux, sometimes it's hard to understand easy problem too.