# Wireless Adapter Does not Work after System Update

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and ran a system update the other week.  Since then, my Wifi adapter has not worked.  I've read through several other threads related to the subject but have decided that it would be best to post the results of the wireless script for my laptop.  Please help.  Also, it will be a pain for me to connect my laptop to a wired connection.

Information from the script is below:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 28 Dec 2016 10:11 EST -0500

Booted last: 12 Dec 2016 11:13 EST -0500

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-51-generic #72~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 24 19:22:30 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu (from ~/.dmrc)

##### lspci #############################

06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0019]

07:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5249 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5249] (rev 01)

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0a5c:216f Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f3:21f9 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 03f0:134a Hewlett-Packard Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0e8d:1887 MediaTek Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:573c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

2: nfc0: NFC
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

dell_wmi               16384  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  1 dell_wmi
mxm_wmi                16384  0 
dell_laptop            20480  0 
dcdbas                 16384  1 dell_laptop
wmi                    20480  2 dell_wmi,mxm_wmi
video                  40960  3 i915,dell_wmi,dell_laptop

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'virbr0' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17040 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16397 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2047348 (2.0 MB)  TX bytes:1618559 (1.6 MB)

vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'virbr0' [IF1]>  
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'virbr0' [IF1]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17040 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:374115 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2285908 (2.2 MB)  TX bytes:20233850 (20.2 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

vnet0     no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0

##### resolv.conf #######################

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      1565     1  0 Dec12 ?        00:00:07 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=<MAC address>,9C:EB:E8:25:26:13,9C:EB:E8:25:26:24,

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ANNEX]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ANNEX | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=ANNEX | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/C24G4]] (600 root)
[connection] id=C24G4 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=C24G4 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/LANT Mifi 4]] (600 root)
[connection] id=LANT Mifi 4 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=LANT Mifi 4 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/gogoinflight]] (600 root)
[connection] id=gogoinflight | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=gogoinflight | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/LANT Mifi 6]] (600 root)
[connection] id=LANT Mifi 6 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=LANT Mifi 6 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/NAVFAC-V5]] (600 root)
[connection] id=NAVFAC-V5 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=NAVFAC-V5 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/hhonors]] (600 root)
[connection] id=hhonors | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=hhonors | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/LANT MIFI 6]] (600 root)
[connection] id=LANT MIFI 6 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=LANT MIFI 6 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/LANT Mifi 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=LANT Mifi 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=LANT Mifi 1 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/insert_awesome_SSID_here]] (600 root)
[connection] id=insert_awesome_SSID_here | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=insert_awesome_SSID_here | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ANNEX2]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ANNEX2 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=ANNEX2 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/DM3 Hotspot]] (600 root)
[connection] id=DM3 Hotspot | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=DM3 Hotspot | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Chaplain Office]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Chaplain Office | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Chaplain Office | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Atlantic CIO 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Atlantic CIO 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Atlantic CIO | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Fairfield_GUEST]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Fairfield_GUEST | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Fairfield_GUEST | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ATT CERT LANT 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ATT CERT LANT 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=ATT CERT LANT 1 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Atlantic CIO]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Atlantic CIO | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Atlantic CIO | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/guestwifi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=guestwifi | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=guestwifi | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/New_York (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0)

##### iwlist channels ###################

vnet0     no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

virbr0    no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

vnet0     Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

virbr0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/netcf.conf]
alias bond0 bonding

[/etc/modprobe.d/qemu-system-x86.conf]
options kvm_intel nested=1

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# USB device 0x:0x (r8152)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x14e4:0x43b1 (wl)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
# USB device 0x:0x (r8152)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
# USB device 0x:0x (r8152)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth2"

##### dmesg #############################

[712130.479786] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-216f.hcd failed with error -2
[712130.479789] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-216f.hcd not found

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Ran sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source and fixed the issue.  Swear I did this several times before and this time it worked.

Comment: I use this http://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline