# <Kubuntu 17.04> Network Manager does not show any WIFI connection or Ethernet connection

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu

I have recently installed Kubuntu on my MacBook Air, using a USB. This is the first time I am using Kubuntu/Ubuntu/Linux.

After installation, I noticed that the Network Manager was entirely blank and only showed the option for Airplane Mode. I tried to go through some documentation and checked what network card I have installed, and what driver I need. The info I got was:

Chip ID: BCM4360

PCI-ID: 14e4:43a0

Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

This meant that I would have to install the Broadcom STA Wireless Driver. However, I also found out that I do not have dkms installed on my Kubuntu. How should I proceed to install the drivers I need? (Can somebody tell me what to do step by step?)

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline