# Problem with wifi drivers ( BCM4322) on Macbook after ubuntu 17.04 instalation

Tags: drivers, wireless, macbook

I installed Ubuntu on an old Macbook. All looks fine but I have a problem with internet connection. Can't connect with wifi, and I can't connect with cable.

All tutorials of drivers installation I find are about wired-connection.  The question is:

- Can I download drivers with other PC, put them on usb and them install on Macbook
- If so - how can I do it?

My wifi hardwere is BCM4322. To know this I enter in terminal

`mariana@mariana-MacBook:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:432b] (rev 01)
   Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:008e]
   Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge 
   Kernel modules: ssb

0: hci0: Bluetooth 
Soft blocked: no 
Hard blocked: no
```

What should I do in order to solve it?

Comment: Would you post the output of this command you run into your question, please?

Comment: ` Enthernet controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 Ethernet (rev b1)          Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN controller (rev 01)`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: We asked to post this output TO YOUR QUESTION. Why did you post it to comments?

Comment: I tried to install  like in the link  but it doesn't work to me. I have a BCM4322  https://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline

Comment: "Didn't work" is not an information. It should work. Try again and be more careful.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, then [edit] your question and explain what you did and what was the terminal output.