# Unable to connect to Internet using Asus PCE-AC68 Wifi Card

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, internet, broadcom

Today I am new to Ubuntu 18.04, and everything is working alright except for my Internet Connection using my Asus PCE-AC68 802.11ac Wifi Card. In the Ubuntu settings it displays "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found". I have tried many different guides and tutorials but nothing seems to work. heres my attempt at downloading my drivers.

First, I ran `lspci -nn` and recieved the following outcome, which is my Wifi Card

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4360 802.11ac 
Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
```

Second, I got the file `bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb` from my Ubuntu 18.04 install USB (usb/pool/restricted/p/bcmwl) and then put it on my desktop. 
I then moved the `dkms` folder from (usb/pool/main/d)

`sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

I Recieved this output

```
(Reading database ... 125680 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-        
0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4) over 
(6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dkms.
Preparing to unpack dkms_2.3-3ubuntu9_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.3-3ubuntu9) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bcmwl-kernel-source:
bcmwl-kernel-source depends on linux-libc-dev; however:
Package linux-libc-dev is not installed.
bcmwl-kernel-source depends on libc6-dev; however:
Package libc6-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package bcmwl-kernel-source (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dkms:
 dkms depends on gcc; however:
  Package gcc is not installed.
 dkms depends on dpkg-dev; however:
  Package dpkg-dev is not installed.
 dkms depends on make | build-essential; however:
  Package make is not installed.
  Package build-essential is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package dkms (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
```

Errors were encountered while processing:
     bcmwl-kernel-source
     dkms

Lastly I ran `sudo modprobe wl` and recieved the following:

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4360 802.11ac 
Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
```

If anyone can see where I went wrong or have another solution, Please let me know

Comment: The error is pretty straight-forward `bcmwl-kernel-source depends on linux-libc-dev; however:
Package linux-libc-dev is not installed.
bcmwl-kernel-source depends on libc6-dev; however:
Package libc6-dev is not installed.` so what you can do is either you connect throught the wired connection and install them (easy, strongly suggested) OR you download these packages with another computer and then install them by hand (OK) OR you [add the usb as a repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Personal)(harder).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar thread: [Dependencies unsatisfied for offline Broadcom installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986827/dependencies-unsatisfied-for-offline-broadcom-installation)

As @dadexix86 mentions, it's preferable if you have a wired connection you can use (temporarily) to download these dependencies. If not, you'll have to download them one by one from some place like Launchpad (e.g. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+package/g++) and then transfer them somehow to your machine. Afterwards you can run the following (roughly in correct order):

`sudo dpkg -i linux-libc-dev_4.15.0-20.21_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libc-dev-bin_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libc6-dev_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libitm1_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libatomic1_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libasan4_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i liblsan0_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libtsan0_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libubsan0_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libcilkrts5_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libmpx2_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libquadmath0_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgcc-7-dev_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i gcc-7_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i gcc_7.3.0-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i make_4.1-9.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i dpkg-dev_1.19.0.5ubuntu2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i libstdc++-7-dev_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i g++-7_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i g++_7.3.0-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i build-essential_12.4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i dkms_2.3-3ubuntu9_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb`