# wifi adapter not found after installing Ubuntu 18.04 on acer v5

Tags: boot, wireless, bios

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Acer v5, initially alongside windows 10. After installing I had no wifi connection. Doing some research on the net for some answers I read a couple of times that I should disable secure boot. I entered the bios and tried to disable it but I could not select that option. It was jumping right from boot mode to change boot order. Instead I changed the boot mode from uefi to legacy boot, thinking that I could change it back if it was not working. When I restarted my laptop it was showing operating system not found but since then I can not enter the bios anymore to change it back to uefi mode. If I press F2 nothing happens.

According to my engineering boyfriend windows could not be saved anymore so I decided to install ubuntu 18.04 in legacy boot instead but it did not fix the network problem. It can still not find the network adapter. We tried a couple of suggestions we found on the internet but nothing is working. It seems that all the necessary packeges did not came with the version of Ubuntu that I downloaded (from the official website) and installed. I can not plug in a cable as I have no port for that so I can not do any updates or install other stuff. The only thing I can do is download it on another computer and put it on a usb stick. We tried to look for the right driver but could not find one for ubuntu and have not been able to install it. This should be the driver version for windows v6.30.223.170 Broadcom

I hope someone can help me fix this problem.[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline/626653#626653

Comment: I followed the instructions in the link you profided but after i put the two files in my home directory it says permission denied. When i enter the commend sudo dpkg -i *.deb it says no such file or directory.

Comment: Probably you copied the files to a wrong place. Home directory is not `/home`. It is your "Home Folder" or whatever it is called. The default folder that is opened in your file manager.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Broadcom wireless drivers offline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline)

Comment: You have really a Broadcom device that needs the `bcmwl-kernel-source` driver.

Comment: I don't understand what command are you trying to run. Copy the files using your mouse by drag & drop. Then run a simple command `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`.

Comment: I added a second pickture with the outcome of the above commend

Comment: Now you did all correctly. But the problem is that in Ubuntu 18.04 `gcc` is not installed by default. This is a real problem and a shame on the developers. If you install the 16.04 release, it will work this way. You will be able to upgrade to 18.04. Manually downloading all `build-essential` is very difficult for a newbie.

Comment: I already thought of a similer solution. I will do that. Thanks

Comment: This is actually a 18.04 serious bug. probably they tried to make the installation file smaller.

Comment: You can download the packages that are missing the same way from the `pool` directory of the installation media.

Answer (score 0):

That is a real problem without an Ethernet connection.

`gcc`, `build-essential`, etc. are not installed by default in `bionic`. This makes it very difficult to install a `dkms` package, or build anything from source without any network connection.

It is possible to download and install many packages manually, but it really a hard work for an ordinary user.

I suggest installing the 16.04 release. It is possible to upgrade it to 18.04 later.

Also I consider it a serious bug, that should be reported to the developers.

I asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044853/build-essential-is-not-installed-by-default-in-18-04-how-to-install-network-dri). I hope someone will find a better solution.

I looked into the 18.04 LiveUSB and found that it seems that the required dependencies are included to `pool`. It is possible to download them manually the same way as `dkms` and `bcmwl-kernel-source`.

Comment: Fixed it :D. I ended up dumping all the packages from the pool folder in my home folder and than ran the comment sudo dpkg -i *.deb. Maybe not the cleanest way but it worked for me. I am now writing my command from my Ubuntu desktop using wifi :)

Comment: P.s my boyfriend has been working on it all evening trying out different codes and solutions so I don' t know to what extant he laid the groundwork for this method to work.

Comment: That is a good comment. It looks like all dependencies are there.