# build-essential is not installed by default in 18.04. How to install network drivers offline?

Tags: networking, wireless, system-installation, 18.04, gcc

We have a serious problem with new installations on laptops that have only a wireless network device requiring some network drivers, like `bcmwl-kernel-source`.

Many laptops don't have an Ethenet port nowadays.

There is no `build-essential` in a default installation. So we can't install a `dkms` module or build anything from source.

The only way is to manually download very many packages required to install `build-essential` and install them manually using `dpkg`.

Is there any other way that an ordinary user can go with?

This question arose from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044789/wifi-adapter-not-found-after-installing-ubuntu-18-04-on-acer-v5).

I suggested to install `xenial` that has `build-essential` by default.

If there is no other Ubuntu installation available, suggesting something like `apt-offline` doesn't seem to be good enough.

It looks like all the required packages are provided on the installation media (pool directory). If anyone could suggest a script or any other simple way to download and install them all, it would be a great answer.

Comment: How about using a live install (if the network driver is working there and chroot into your installation and install build-essentials and the neetwork driver this way?

Comment: Why do you think it is working there?

Comment: at least on my crappy old laptop where the wifi driver is not installed by default wifi is running however from a live boot. Was just a guess and an idea which came up as i have read your question.

Comment: As a workaround I can suggest to build a `wl.ko` against the kernel that goes with the distro and make it available for everyone.

Comment: @Videonauth I don't think `wl` works form a LiveUSB. I can be wrong. I don't have a device to test it.

Comment: Building it could be an option too, what all the time works is normal network, so a cat cable just as jump start could work too.

Comment: Many laptops don't have Ethernet.

Comment: Mobile data + USB tethering may be a feasible option for some.

Comment: Let's focus on solutions not requiring additional hardware.

Comment: There is a hint. It looks like the required packages are on installation media in `pool` directory.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain `build-essential` isn't installed by default in any version of Ubuntu. `gcc` was, but no longer. `make`, `g++`, the rest, nope. That said, if those packages are on the USB, the correct way would be to use the USB as a repository (using `apt-cdrom`, iirc?), and use apt-get as usual.

Comment: @muru Dkms did install with no problems, but it requires `make`.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/741753/how-to-use-cubic-to-create-a-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-image

Answer (score 1):

Nobody answered the question, so I'll try to post my suggestions that are not perfect.

One comparatively easy way to solve this problem is to connect temporarily to the internet using an Android phone or some other device. Then it is possible to install the driver a normal way.

Another way is to install `dkms` from an Ubuntu installation media. All required dependencies are there in `pool` directory. If you download all deb packages from there to Ubuntu Home directory, it will be possible to install all packages by `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`.

There must be a way to connect the Ubuntu installation media as a repo and install `dkms` using `apt install`. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: As to your last sentence: Of course there is! You can use old days' `apt-cdrom`, or use `file:` URL inn your `sources.list`.

Comment: If you write an answer describing that, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have a similar question here. I wonder if you know how to suggest an imperfect solution? :) https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277732/getting-make-build-essential-and-ethernet-drivers-installed-on-ubuntu-18-04-ma