# Problems with my Lenovo Ideapad 320

Tags: networking, drivers, lenovo, realtek-wireless

I have been using Ubuntu now for a while on my desktop and didn't have any big problems with it. I directly removed Windows 10 from my new laptop and installed Ubuntu 18.04.

Now there arrive the problems ^^.

I'm not able to get any Internet connection whatsoever, neither am I able to get a W-lan connection nor am I able to connect via Ethernet cable directly.

I have been looking for a driver for my RTL8821CE, but I quickly realized that I still have to learn a lot about how to handle Ubuntu correctly. (this is the driver that I downloaded: https://github.com/endlessm/linux/tree/master/drivers/net/wireless/rtl8821ce)
I noticed that I have to make the file some how to build the driver, but the problem is I don't have the make package. So my thought was to just download the package on my Desktop put it on a usb-stick and install it on my laptop. But when I try that nothing happens, like literally I enter my sudo and nothing happens.

---

**CONCLUSION for anyone who wants to cut the description:**

I have ***no*** internet connection and need to get the required packages on my laptop to build the driver for my Realtek card in order to download any other packages.

After entering `uname -a`, I get:

```
Linux initBasti 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP ...UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: That is a big problem with 18.04. There is no `build-essential` and it is hard to install it without any network. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044853/build-essential-is-not-installed-by-default-in-18-04-how-to-install-network-dri

Comment: So.. should I install a different OS? Like an older version of Ubuntu?

Comment: If you install 16.04, at least you'll be able to build drivers out-of the-box.

Comment: Ok, I think I try that, thank you :) It is just weird for me why build essential isn't part of Ubuntu 18.04, doesnt really make sense for me^^.