# No internet access Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, 18.04

I am using a Dell laptop Intel Core 2 Duo CPU with 4G RAM and wiped Windows Vista off it to replace it with Ubuntu 18.04. I installed the OS tonight and the wifi light went off and no wifi recognition panel appears when I log on (I am typing this on my wifi connected windows PC). When I use an ethernet cable firefox states 'we can't connect to the server at...' so it's like I don't have wired or wifi access on the laptop at all, although it worked before I installed Ubuntu. 
I tried to update the Broadcom drivers in additional drivers and selecting apply changes didn't work, it wouldn't update at all.
So basically - wifi worked on this laptop pre-Ubuntu (eg - yesterday) and now doesn't work at all, nor does wireless. I am a complete noob at linux and my 'restore new life to old laptop' hasn't got off to a great start! Any help appreciated.

```
    rfkill list - ethernet controller {0200} Broadcom Limited NetLink BCM5784M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1698] (rev 10)
Subsystem: Dell Netlink BCM5784M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [1028:0256]
    Kernel driver in use : tg3
    Kernel modules : tg3
    0c:00.0 Network controller [0280] : Broadcom Limited BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [13e4: 432b} (rev 01)
    Subsystem : Dell Wireless 1510 Wireless -N WLAN Mini-Card [1028: 000d]
    kernel driver in use : b43-pci-bridge
    kernel modules : ssb
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I don't see the Network controller code. You need to install either `firmware-b43-installer`, or `bcmwl-kernel-source`. Both can be installed offline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: With 18.04 it is a bit more complex to install `bcmwl-kernel-source`. You need to copy many packages from `pool`. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline/626653#626653

Comment: The easiest way is to connect to the internet using your phone.

Comment: OK well I've attached my phone (which is wifi) and tethered it to the laptop and still nothing working

Answer (score 2):

Connect to the internet using your phone. You can connect almost any phone by USB and use it as a modem.

Then run in a terminal

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

With the 18.04 Ubuntu version it is not very straight forward to install Broadcom drivers offline.

Comment: Thanks I've just tried that and got lots of errors back stating E:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms etc. (pages of it) Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com' Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` first.

Comment: If you haven't set up USB tethering, and you use Android, there are instructions [here](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2812516?hl=en). That will give your laptop a temporary internet connection (assuming your phone has one) to download the Wi-Fi driver.

Comment: Thanks all, the software updater is in overdrive installing updates so I think some form of internet must be working?