# Wifi Not detected in 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, broadcom

I am new to Ubuntu 20.04.

I was using windowsXP and i did a dual boot in my pc.

It looks everything is good but i am not able to detect wifi connection.

```
$ iwconfig
    
enp7s0    no wireless extensions.
    
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

and

```
lspci -knn 

ETHERNET CONTROLLER [0200]: Intel Corporation PRO/100 VE Network Connection [8086:1092] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company PRO/100 VE Network Connection [103c:30bb]
Kernel driver in use: e100
Kernel modules: e100
```

I read responses to similar thread and some suggested installing `bcmwl-kernel-source`
On trying that I get an error :

```
Unable to locate package bcmwl-kernel-source
```

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net; rfkill list
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev02)
05:08.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation PRO/100 VE Network Connection [8086:1092] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company PRO/100 VE Network Connection [103c:30bb]
0: hp-wifi Wireless LAN
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Look for wireless in the `lspci` list, not for ethernet.

Comment: i dont have wireless in lspci list

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Are you using a built-in adapter or some USB dongle?

Comment: Do you know any details about this wireless device?

Comment: 1. output of lspci -knn | grep Net; rfkill list  - added in original post
2. Its builts in adapter
3. i can gather all details which are required to fix the issue

Comment: Connect to the internet using e.g. your phone and install `firmware-b43-installer`

Comment: You might need to run `sudo apt-add-repository universe && sudo apt update` first and then run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Answer (score 2):

You have BCM4311 wireless. You will need wired Internet connection to fix it.
Open Terminal and type: `sudo apt install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer`
Then reboot.

Comment: It says 
Unable to locate package b43-fwcutter
Unable to locate package firmware-b43-installer

Comment: I says that because you are not connected to the internet.

Comment: @lev248 You don't need to include `b43-fwcutter` to the command It will be pulled  by `firmware-b43-installer`.

Comment: understood , but then how do i connect to internet ?
you had suggested using phone , do you mean by using usb connector ?

Comment: You can use USB, or a cable connection. There is also an offline guide in the linked answer. https://askubuntu.com/a/1244412/167850

Comment: I had the same problem with a HP dv6000 with the Broadcom 4311. No dual boot just loaded Linux Mint 19.3.and annihilated Vista. Everything went fine with the Ethernet connection but it did not find my WiFi. Spent hours researching and downloading suggested fixes which changed the configuration of my system. Finally yesterday decided to restore to my original config by using Time shift. Today I did what Lev258 suggested and it worked. Even though I had used that command a couple of times before it didn't work because I had changed the configuration of the original download.