# Missing WiFi drivers on old Mac

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers

I am having trouble with the Wifi drivers on my new instillation of Ubuntu. This is my first time using Linux, but I am familiar with Unix from OS X. I have replaced OS X with Ubuntu on an older model Macintosh.
  I have done a little research on the problem yielding no solutions.

Using `sudo lshw -C network`, I can gather that I have a BCM4322 card (Wireless LAN Controller). But when I try to get the PCI ID with `lspci -mn -d 14e4:`, I get `"0280" "14e4" "432b" -r01 "106b" "008e"`, which I don't understand.

So how can I acquire the appropriate drivers?

It may also be worth mentioning that there are no wireless extensions when using the command `iwconfig`.

Thanks for taking the time to read and answer,
AidoP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the package `firmware-b43-installer`:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

You will need to enable the `multiverse` repository to be able to do this. If you chose to install 3rd party software when installing Ubuntu, then it should already be enabled. If not, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository).

You may need to restart your computer afterwards for the card to start working.

Comment: I get the error "Unable to locate package". I also got this when trying to install the Java development kit 8. It may be worth mentioning I am using Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Read the full answer! ;-) "You will need to enable the `multiverse` repository" - check this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository. If you've done that, run `sudo apt-get update` and then try installing it again.

Comment: Ok, it's going now. I have a very slow internet connection, so it will be a while until the update is finished. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: That's awesome ☺

Answer (score 0):

Please see: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395) The correct driver for your device `14e4:432b` is bcmwl-kernel-source:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot.