# virtualbox installlation requirement

Tags: software-installation

What are the requirements for installing VirtualBox from the Ubuntu software center? I tried to download from the center but it says that there is additional software that is missing...

I am a new user.

Comment: If the installation fails there should be a dialog providing information about the failure. Please provide it.

Comment: To be able to install virtualbox from the software center you may have to [enable the multiverse repository](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository). For the closed source more update version see http://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack

Answer (score 2):

I rarely install VirtualBox from the Ubuntu Software Center, because it is always outdated. I will show you how to install it manually:

Download the version with your correct architecture:

- [i386](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.28/virtualbox-4.3_4.3.28-100309~Ubuntu~raring_i386.deb)
- [amd64](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.28/virtualbox-4.3_4.3.28-100309~Ubuntu~raring_amd64.deb)

Save the file in your home folder, then start up the terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, and then run the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-4.3_4.3.28-100309~Ubuntu~raring_*.deb
```

After that, if it still gives you a missing packages list, try:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Last, but not least, you need to install the [VirtualBox 4.3.28 Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.28/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.28-100309.vbox-extpack), after download, open it with VirtualBox, and you're done.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

what about downloading .deb package directly from Oracle and installing it with

```
sudo dpkg -i packageName.deb
```

in terminal?

If something is missing, you can anyway try to find missing packages via

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Cheers,

Silvia