# How to unpack file with a .pak extension?

Tags: 14.04, compression

I would like to unpack a `.pak` file on Ubuntu 14.04.

*How should I proceed?*

Answer (score 3):

**1. method**

- Install p7zip via terminal:

`sudo apt-get install p7zip-full`

- Or use Software Center:

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/p7zip-full/

It should be capable of opening `.pak` files

---

**2. method**

- Install `Unrar (non-free)` from Software Center, where `multiverse repos` must be enabled!

[How do I enable the "multiverse" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository)

- or from source:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unrar-nonfree

---

**3. method**

*Install WinRAR via Wine*

- Download WinRAR (I would go with x86 version):

http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm

- Install the application:

http://www.howtogeek.com/105271/how-to-run-windows-software-on-ubuntu-with-wine/

---

**4. method (overkill)**

- Install Windows in Virtual Box, after that install Winrar and see if it works.

IF IT IS A GAME FILE: Many games have their own extractor. Unless you know exactly what program made it, AND you can find the proper extractor, AND you have all the files (if split) you're out of luck.

---

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAK_%28file_format%29

Comment: didn't work for me..

Comment: edited my answer ;)

Comment: both unrar and p7zip do not work on 19.10

Answer (score 1):

This is a long-dead thread, but here is some information that may be of help if anyone should need to work with PAK files:

I tried p7zip but it does not recognize the .PAK file extension (even in lower case.)

/usr/bin/p7zip: SONGS.PAK: unknown suffix -- ignored

There was a program called PAKF.EXE that was copyrighted 1988 by NoGate Consulting which supported the PAK file extension.  It ran in Windows.  I ran it today in DOSBox on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine (but my copy is copyrighted so I should not share it.)

This site [ https://www.sac.sk/files.php?d=7&l=P ] lists several compression tools, including pak251.exe by NoGate Consulting. The exe is downloadable and there are many other compression tools in the list as well.

Answer (score 0):

The definitive approach to extracting .PAK from Quake and Quake II or similar games is this little utility called qunpak: https://indigo.re/qunpak/.

You just download the [file](https://gitlab.com/hydrargyrum/attic/-/raw/master/qunpak/qunpak?inline=false), `chmod +x` it and if you plan on using it again, either `sudo mv` it to `/usr/local/bin` or just `mv` it to `~/.local/bin`. That's going to add it to PATH so you would be able to use it as any other command.

Then just `qunpak -x` the file in question. If unsure, consult `qunpak --help` or [the README.md](https://gitlab.com/hydrargyrum/attic/-/blob/master/qunpak/README.md)