# Can't download software's from Ubuntu Software center ( 14.04 LTS )

Tags: 14.04, package-management, software-center, multiverse

[image: A screenshot from software center]

When I tried to install software's (say Play on Linux / Eclipse), The software center says that `Available from multiverse source` and there is only a button `Use this Source`. At the same time I can remove softwares which I installed earlier.
I tried via `Terminal` but it says that

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package`
```

I tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt), But no visible change. the above result repeated and No install button on Software Center

Comment: have you tried rebooting? i kow this sounds silly but that solves the problem most of the time

Comment: open terminal and type `sudo reboot` it's also known as **restart** if you're familiar with that term

Comment: I tried it. But no change. I think it will be fixed by enabling the multiverse source in my Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @muru .I am still unable to solve this problem.  i tried your possible answer [https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt] . But still I can't any visible change. What will I do ????

Answer (score 0):

**only for terminal problem**

this happence because ur typing incorrect spelings of the packages.also you shoul not use capital leatters in terminal for package name.to viwe package name download synaptic package manager.then search the softwere name which u want to install and it will give you list of avilable packages.now type this package name in terminal

```
sudo apt install package-name
```

now to download synaptic package manager type following command

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

**now if these command did not work then type following commands respectively**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

now try again the upper command which i just mentioned.

also try changing your server by going in software and updates [try changing your severer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgKNP.png)

also your Ubuntu version is old. you should update you os to 16.04 lts which is last resort

if this dose not work then inform me by leaving comment under this answer

Comment: IT WORKS, I solved my problem by [this way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository) . @smit patil  I think your answer is not much helpful to me. Because my  PC already  updated in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS(Not upgraded into Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) and the software already supporting in this version.

Comment: is your problem solved or not ?

Comment: please inform me if your problem is solved or not so can help further

Comment: Solved by [this way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository)

Comment: i did my best to solve your promblem.also i am glad that your promblem is solved.but trust me bud,i have same problem which i just solved by changing serever.