# FSLview didn't display properly in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation

I have installed all the packages. When I type fslview &, it didn't show any error message. However, it didn't work. It also didn't display any header at all. I cannot loading any file from my PC. Can anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

[when I type "fslview &", this is the pop up window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJrcO.png)

Output of `lsb_release -a`

> LSB Version: core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubunt‌​                u0.2-noarch:security‌​-9.20160110ubuntu0.2‌​-amd64:security-9.20‌​160110ubuntu0.2-noar‌​ch Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS Release: 16.04 Codename: xenial

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please help us help you by providing further detail. How did you install fslview? What is the output of `lsb_release -a`

Comment: Hi there, I am follow this http://neuro.debian.net/pkgs/fslview.html instruction to install the package. The output of lsb_release -a as below: LSB Version: core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By placing an ampersand `&` at the end of the line you are attempting to start fslview in the background which is doubtless not your intent if you expect to actually see something. The command line structure as found on the [man page](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/fslview/) is as follows:

`fslview [-m <viewmode>] [<baseimage> [imageoptions] ... ]`

There's really no need to jump through hoops installing this as it's part of the [fsl package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=fsl&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) available in the [multiverse repository.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository)

If anything about this answer is unclear, please drop me a comment and I'll do my best to clarify.