# how to install triangle quake into ubuntu on virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I am new here.. especially on using Ubuntu..

I am currently using virtualbox to run Ubuntu.. I am trying to install triangle quake which is a A Two-Dimensional Quality Mesh Generator and Delaunay Triangulator.

->
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html
->

according to this site:
https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/trusty/triangle-bin

All I need to do is update then install it using terminal, I have been doing it but still nothing is installed? there are no error message at all!!

I am already a superuser(if ever wonder if that is the cause)

I installed both 16 & 14 ubuntu version in my virtualbox. & still has no improvement.. is there any method to install it that I missed?

please help me..

Comment: Are you sure that it's not installed? What is the output of `which triangle`?

Answer (score 1):

[Triangle is provided from the Ubuntu Multiverse software repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/triangle-bin). After we had [enabled the Multiverse repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository) it can be installed with:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install triangle-bin
```

The installed application [triangle](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/triangle.6x) will be called from the command line:

```
triangle  [-display  host:display.screen]  [-visual  visual]  [-window]
   [-root] [-delay number] [-ncolors number] [-fps]
```

For options see the [manpage for triangle](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/triangle.6x).

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for.. it work!!