# Unable to install unrar on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, rar

I have been unable to extract .rar files from the Archive Manager and so followed some instructions online on how else that can be done.

The xarchiver application does not install from the Software Manager and when I try to install unrar from the terminal, I get the following:

```
 :~$ sudo apt-get install unrar
 [sudo] password for:  
 Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state
 information... Done Package unrar is not available, but is referred to
 by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has
 been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

 E: Package 'unrar' has no installation candidate
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Was you do `apt update` before `apt install unrar`? What returns `apt search unrar`?

Comment: Hi there, but apt update do you mean an update for all available applications or specifically unrar?

And what is the command for searching for unrar in the Terminal?

Comment: Was you read my full comment? Was you saw the second question?

Check if you have "multiverse" repository enabled on your system.

Comment: Have you enabled the multiverse repository? See here https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository#553847 on how to do this.

Comment: Thank you, I just ran the command to enable the multiverse repository.

Comment: @mariaczi sorry, just saw your comment now :(

Comment: It's alright. The multiverse repo has been updated, but I still get the same response when I try to install unrar.  Is there something else I should be doing now?

Comment: This is happening because Ubuntu 17.04 is pass end-of-life and unsupported, so its repositories have been removed.

Answer (score 3):

## multiverse

unrar is not contained in the standard Ubuntu repository. You need to enable the multiverse repository in order to install it. To do this run the following command:

```
sudo apt-add-repository multiverse && sudo apt-get update
```

as described here: [How do I enable the "multiverse" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository#553847)

On Ubuntu 17.04 (zesty) this package was called `unrar-nonfree`, so to install unrar you would need to issue `sudo apt-get install unrar-nonfree`.

But since 17.04 is not supported anymore you should really upgrade your system anyway.

Comment: Yes I've enabled the multiverse repository now but I'm still getting the same message when I try to install unrar.  What else should I do?